# how to design custom template in socialengine4 framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, themes

As I am new to socialengine4 so i am having trouble in designing custom template. I want to convert HTML/CSS template into Socialengine4 module.
Example:

[image]

Suppose this is the template and i want to design it into socialengine4.

1. how can i create custom layout like above template ?
2. How can i create custom common page elements like header, footer ?

What are the directory structure as well as file structure to get above two points.

**Note:** I need to create it manually not from the layouts provided default in Admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

Under the article [`Creating Your Own Theme`](http://www.socialengine.net/support/documentation/article?q=128&question=Creating-Your-Own-Theme), SocialEngine documentation provides all the necessary details to create own theme from scratch.